# IntelliSense cannot find ViewComponent Invoke() method in Razor Pages project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, razor-pages

I get this IntelliSense error message in Visual Studio error console every time I open any .cshtml file in the project:

```
Could not find an 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' method for the view component 'xxxxxxx'
```

All my view components have Invoke() or InvokeAsync() methods in them. When I run the project, everything works fine and all view components are rendered properly, so I think my code is not a problem here.

Anyone encountered this problem in VS IntelliSense before? I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.6 and project is running on asp.net 5.0.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.. I have a base view component class that has a type parameter of IViewComponentViewModel abstraction.  That implements the Invoke method on the Base class.. .then all view component classes get that default implementation for the Invoke.. My project builds and runs fine. When I open the cshtml file that uses the view component <vc:whatever view-model="Model.WhateverViewModel" /> it shows the same error. If I close the file the error disappears... Not a huge deal but annoying and misleading..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved after installing Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Intellisense for your project is broken due to some personal steps. To solve it, you have to close your project, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

After that, restart your project and I hope that your issue will disappear.

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately this did not help to fix the problem. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: If you create a new project with the same code, did the issue happen again?